# App not responding and user permission error

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I have two problems:

1. When the register button is clicked, the application stops responding and the database is not saved.
2. After selecting the photo using the select button, I get a user permission error when I click on the upload button. I don't know why this is happening because I've added all the required permissions in the manifest.

**Here is my code**

```
public class JobSignup extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btnChoose, btnUpload;
private ImageView imageView;
private Uri filePath;
private final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 71;
//private EditText Email_editText , Password_editText , Name_editText;
private Button Register_button ;
private EditText inName, inEmail, inPassword, inDateOfBirth, inAddress,
        inRePassword,inExperiences,inQualification,inSkills;
private FirebaseAuth fAuth;
private DatabaseReference fUserDatabase;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
FirebaseStorage storage;
StorageReference storageReference;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_job_signup);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    storageReference = storage.getReference();



    btnChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChoose);
    btnUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);


    Register_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);
    inEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
    inName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUsername);
    inPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
    inRePassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editConfirmPassword);
    inDateOfBirth = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editDateOfBirth);
    inAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAddress);
    inExperiences = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editExperiences);
    inQualification = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editQualification);
    inSkills = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAdditionalSkills);

    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    fUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User");


    btnChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            chooseImage();
        }
    });

    btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            uploadImage();
        }
    });

    Register_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String uEmail = inEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String uName = inName.getText().toString().trim();
            String uPassword = inPassword.getText().toString().trim();
            String uRePassword = inRePassword.getText().toString().trim();
            String uDateOfBirth = inDateOfBirth.getText().toString().trim();
            String uAddress = inAddress.getText().toString().trim();
            String uExperiences = inExperiences.getText().toString().trim();
            String uQualification=inQualification.
           getText().toString().trim();
            String uSkills = inSkills.getText().toString().trim();
            register_user(uName,uEmail,uPassword,uRePassword,uAddress,
          uDateOfBirth,uExperiences,uQualification,uSkills);
        }
    });
}
private void register_user(final String name, final String email, String 
 password,final String rePassword,final String Qualification,final String 
Experiences,final String Skills,final String address , final String 
DateOfBirth){

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Processing your data, Please wait . . .");
    progressDialog.show();

    fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, 
password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                fUserDatabase.child(fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                        .child("name").setValue(name)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() 
{
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) 
 {
                                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();

  fUserDatabase.child(fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()). 
child("DateOfBirth").setValue(DateOfBirth);


     fUserDatabase.child(fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Address"). 
   setValue(address);

fUserDatabase.child(fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()). 
 child("Email").setValue(email);

   fUserDatabase.child(fAuth.getCurrentUser(). 
  getUid()).child("Qualification").setValue(Qualification);

  fUserDatabase.child(fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Experiences"). 
   setValue(Experiences);

    fUserDatabase.child(fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Skills"). 
  setValue(Skills);

                                    Intent i = new Intent(JobSignup.this, 
 Login.class);
                                    startActivity(i);
                                    finish();
                                    Toast.makeText(JobSignup.this, "User has 
  been created!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }else{
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(JobSignup.this, "Error: "+ 
   task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }else{
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(JobSignup.this, "Error: "+ 
    task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}


private void chooseImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 
  PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && data != null && data.getData() != null )
    {
        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = 
  MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void uploadImage() {

    if (filePath != null) {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("images/" + 
UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        ref.putFile(filePath)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new 
OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot 
taskSnapshot) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(JobSignup.this, "Uploaded", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(JobSignup.this, "Failed " + 
 e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new 
 OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot 
  taskSnapshot) {
                        double progress = (100.0 * 
  taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot
                                .getTotalByteCount());
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + (int) 
 progress + "%");
                    }
                });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: For the solution please post Error Log cat.

Answer (score 0):

- Ensure you added this permission to `manifest` file.

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  ```
- Add this line with `chosseImage` method.

  ```
  private void chooseImage() {
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setType("image/*");
  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); // temp permission for receiving app to read this file
  startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
  }
  ```
- Update `onActivityResult` to scale bitmap with parent size to avoid `OutOfMemory`, Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object) for more details.

  ```
          // Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
          // imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

          BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
          Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath,bmOptions);
          bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,parent.getWidth(),parent.getHeight(),true);
          imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
  ```